# Which martial arts actor emulates Bruce Lee's fighting style most faithfully?

Tags: history, style, entertainment, bruce-lee

The three depictions of Bruce Lee that I've seen are Jason Scott Lee in *Dragon: The Bruce Lee Story*, Danny Chan in the *Ip Man* films, and Mike Moh in *Once Upon A Time In Hollywood* (although I'd rather forget this last one).

Is there a martial arts actor/actress today who emulates Bruce Lee's fighting style particularly well, regardless of whether they played the man himself?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BruceLeeClone

Comment: @MacacoBranco Wasn't sure if that was a serious suggestion or not, looking at the top of the page. Then I saw the comments in the live-action section, and it seems like Jet Li and Alexander Fu Sheng match what I was looking for, as in a successor, rather than a clone/wannabe. (Oh, and btw, thanks for sucking me into the vortex that is TVTropes - love it, but might be gone for a few days! :D)

Comment: Glad I could help. Personally, I think the question kind of comes down to an opinion, but I figured that would provide a pointer for you.

Comment: Appreciated :) Possibly is opinion-based, although I was trying to avoid that - getting to grips with how it all works.